EXM does not show scheduled emails for recurring campaigns
When I create a recurring regular email campaign, before it starts I can see it in the scheduled tab on EXM but after it sends the first email I can't see the next scheduled emails for this campaign just the sent ones. Is this a default EXM behavior? If so, can I do anything to see the next scheduled emails in the scheduled tab?
